# is it the urls or the views?

Tags: django

seem like it should work... but..
here is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from create_lesson.models import Lesson
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from add_material.models import Materials

def Use_Lesson(request, lesson):
    user=request.user
    lessons = Lesson.objects.get(slug=lesson)
    lessons.attributes=Materials.objects.filter(lesson=lessons.pk)
    context = {'user':user,'lesson':lessons,}
    return render_to_response('use_lesson/use_lesson.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns= patterns('',
    (r'^browse/', 'use_lesson.views.Browse'),
    (r'^lesson/(?P<lesson>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', 'use_lesson.views.Use_Lesson'),
```

here is the basic error message
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    .../lesson/superfarts
Django Version:     1.4.1
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    Lesson matching query does not exist.

and it is saying the problem is here:  lessons = Lesson.objects.get(slug=lesson)

when i do the same the same query in "python manage.py shell"
i get the results i am looking for.

Comment: Verify on shell that you are doing the exactly same query, with exaclt same value for `lesson`.

Comment: Specifically, make sure that `Lesson.objects.get(slug='superfarts')` in the manage.py shell gets you the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change it as:

```
(r'^lesson/(?P<lesson>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', 'use_lesson.views.Use_Lesson')
```

Comment: this one worked thanks! but iI dont really understand the difference?

Comment: i look now again and seems your original url should work. could you print in view `lesson` var?

Answer (score 0):

A slugfield is best represented in a regexp by \W which is equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

```
(r'^lesson/(?P<lesson>\W+)/$', 'use_lesson.views.Use_Lesson')
```

Comment: thanks ... this looks like it should work but for some reason it didnt?